# Some services are not able to be constructed ASP .NET 6 With EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

When I try to run my code error are displayed as (Some services are not able to be constructed)

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User]'.)

```
System.AggregateException
      HResult=0x80131500
      Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User]'.)
      Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
      StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
       at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\user1\source\repos\Proj.E-Invoice\Proj.E-Invoice\Program.cs:line 37
    
      This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
        [External Code]
    
    Inner Exception 1:
    InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User]'.
    
    Inner Exception 2:
    InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment.User]'.
```

When I try to remove this code the project will run successfully..

```cs
IdentityBuilder identityBuilder = builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<User>(pass =>
{
    pass.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    pass.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
    pass.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    pass.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    pass.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    pass.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
});
```

**Program.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.DotNet.Scaffolding.Shared.ProjectModel;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Text;
using Proj.Core;
using Proj.Core.IRepositories;
using Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment;
using Proj.EF;
using Proj.EF.Seed;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

string conStr = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? 
    throw new Exception("Connection string not defined!");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(conStr, b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(DataContext).Assembly.FullName)));

IdentityBuilder identityBuilder = builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<User>(pass =>
{
    pass.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    pass.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
    pass.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    pass.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    pass.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    pass.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
});

//builder.Services.AddTransient<ISeed, Seed>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

var app = builder.Build();

//using (var obj = app.Services.CreateScope())
//{
//    var services = obj.ServiceProvider;

//    var seeder = services.GetRequiredService<Seed>();

//    seeder.SeedRolesAndUsers();
//}

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

**DataContext class: **
DataContext.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Proj.Core.Models;
using Proj.Core.Models.UserManagment;

namespace Proj.EF
{
    public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, long, 
        IdentityUserClaim<long>, UserRole, IdentityUserLogin<long>,
        IdentityRoleClaim<long>, IdentityUserToken<long>>
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Package> Packages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PackagesHistory> PackagesHistories { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Country>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Cities)
            .WithOne(c => c.Country)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.CountryId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>(userRole =>
            {
                userRole.HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });

                userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
                    .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                    .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                    .IsRequired();

                userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
                    .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                    .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                    .IsRequired();
            });

            modelBuilder.Properties()
            .Where(x => x.Name == "Id")
            .Configure(p => p.SetColumnName("Id"));

            modelBuilder.EntityTypes()
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(e => e.SetTableName(e.GetTableName()));

            modelBuilder.Properties()
                        .Where(x => x.Name == "Id")
                        .Configure(p => p.SetIdentityIncrement(1));

            modelBuilder.Properties()
                .Where(x => x.Name == "Id")
                .Configure(p => p.IsPrimaryKey());


            #region Change Names For Tables

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable(name: "User");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable(name: "Role");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("UserRoles");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<long>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("UserClaims");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<long>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("UserLogins");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<long>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("RoleClaims");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<long>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("UserTokens");
            });

            #endregion
        }
    }
```

**Error Description**:

Comment: You are using roles, so why not `.AddIdentity<User, Role>(...`?

Comment: @IvanStoev Same error thrown also brother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This case resolved by doing the following steps:

1.In class Program.cs Replace this code

```
IdentityBuilder identityBuilder = builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<User>(pass =>
{
    pass.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    pass.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
    pass.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    pass.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    pass.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    pass.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
});
```

With:

```
IdentityBuilder identityBuilder = builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(pass =>
{
    pass.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    pass.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
    pass.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    pass.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    pass.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    pass.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```